# How to drag image on a specific path on touch event in android

Tags: android, animation, drag-and-drop, touch, curve

I have drawn a semicircle on canvas as the image below.

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4kj0wesuny-eEVsTjNNVlRYTDg/edit

I want to move the image only on the semicircle and it will stop at defined point on the semicircle.

Here is my code:

Firstly, init an image

```
public DrawView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    setFocusable(true); //necessary for getting the touch events

    Point point = new Point();
    point.x = 65;
    point.y = 665;
    //ball width, height = 70;

    colorball = new ColorBall(context,R.drawable.bol_blauw, point);

}
```

Then draw semicircle and the ball image

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(colorballs.getBitmap(), (float)colorball.getX(), (float)colorball.getY(), null);

    Paint circlePaint = new Paint() {
        {
            setColor(Color.GREEN);
            setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
            setAntiAlias(true);
        }
    };

    circlePaint.setStrokeWidth(3);
    final Path path = new Path();
    rectF = new RectF();
    rectF.set(100, 200, 600, 700);
    float xStart = 100;
    float yStart = 700;

    float xEnd = 600;
    float yEnd = 700;
    float angle = 180;
    float startAngle = getSemicircle(xStart, yStart, xEnd, yEnd, rectF);
    Log.i("Start Angle", "" + startAngle);

    path.addArc(rectF, startAngle, angle);
    canvas.drawPath(path, circlePaint);
}
```

Using this code to draw semicircle

```
public static float getSemicircle(float xStart, float yStart, float xEnd,
        float yEnd, RectF ovalRectOUT) {

    centerX = xStart + ((xEnd - xStart) / 2);
    centerY = yStart + ((yEnd - yStart) / 2);

    double xLen = (xEnd - xStart);
    double yLen = (yEnd - yStart);
    radius = (float) (Math.sqrt(xLen * xLen + yLen * yLen) / 2);

    RectF oval = new RectF((float) (centerX - radius),
            (float) (centerY - radius), (float) (centerX + radius),
            (float) (centerY + radius));

    ovalRectOUT.set(oval);

    double radStartAngle = 0;

    radStartAngle = Math.atan2(yStart - centerY, xStart - centerX);

    float startAngle = (float) Math.toDegrees(radStartAngle);

    return startAngle;

}
```

Using touch event to control the position of the ball, make the ball move only on the semicircle.

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int eventaction = event.getAction(); 

    int X = (int)event.getX(); 
    int Y = (int)event.getY(); 

    switch (eventaction ) { 

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: // touch down so check if the finger is on a ball
        // check if inside the bounds of the ball (circle)
        // get the center for the ball
        int centerX = (int) (colorball.getX() + 25);
        int centerY = (int) (colorball.getY() + 25);

        // calculate the radius from the touch to the center of the ball
        double radCircle  = Math.sqrt( (double) (((centerX-X)*(centerX-X)) + (centerY-Y)*(centerY-Y)));             
         break; 


    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:   // touch drag with the ball
        // move the balls the same as the finger
            double angle = getAngle(colorball.getX(), colorballs.getY());
            colorball.setX(centerX - radius*Math.cos(angle));
            colorball.setY(centerY - radius*Math.sin(angle));
        }

        break; 

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: 
        // touch drop - just do things here after dropping

         break; 
    } 
    // redraw the canvas
    invalidate(); 
    return true; 

}
```

getAngle() function

```
public double getAngle(double ballX, double ballY){
    double newAngle = (Math.abs(centerY - ballY)/(centerX-ballX))*(180/Math.PI);
    return newAngle;
}
```

I didn't succeed. The ball didn't move on the semicircle. Any advice, guidance or example will help me a lot.